# Comparing List<String> to String

Tags: java, arrays, windows, list, compare

I've been having a bit of an issue with my assignment. After reading from an input.txt file, I've created an array in which all of the information has been stored in, but for some reason I seem to be unable to compare them individually. I've tried equals() and contains() I can't think of anything else that would work. what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public static void readFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String inputText = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] splited = null;

    //splitting the text file   
    while((inputText = inputFile.readLine())!= null) {
        splited = inputText.split("[;^:]");
        for (String part : splited) {
        list.add(part); 
        }
    }

    String [] stockArr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    // verify contents of array
    for(int index = 0; index < stockArr.length;index++) {
    System.out.println(stockArr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i > stockArr.length; i++) {
        if(stockArr[i].equals("BusinessContact")) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I were to print this, it does not print "test" but rather only

```
BusinessContact
firstName=Victor
middleName=Garces
lastName=Guana
Address
addressType=WORK
streetName=Athabasca Hall
streetNumber=2-32
apartmentNumber=4-52
city=Edmonton
postalCode=T6G 2E8
country=Canada
```

Answer (score 5):

Check your run-condition for the second for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i > stockArr.length; i++){
    if(stockArr[i].equals("BusinessContact")){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

I think you rather meant

```
for (int i = 0; i < stockArr.length; i++){
    if(stockArr[i].equals("BusinessContact")){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never facepalm so hard before. Thank you so much.

Comment: Next time simply use a debugger and experience the disappointment, when the for-loop is skipped without a single run through :-)

Answer (score 4):

The last `for` loop should have a `<` in its condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stockArr.length; i++){
```

Comment: I'm generally surprised I missed that. Thank you very much!